# Why is Waya's username Zelda?

Tags: hikaru-no-go

In *Hikaru no Go*, Waya's username when playing Go online is Zelda. In the anime the reason wasn't explained (I haven't read the manga, so maybe the explanation is in there). The first thing I think of when I see the name Zelda is *The Legend of Zelda* video game franchise, so I tried to find out if the username was a reference to that, but I couldn't find out anything online. I'm interested in both Waya's reasons (if available) and the author's for using the username Zelda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explanation given in the manga about Waya using the nickname "Zelda".

However, the adult person explaining computer/internet go to Hikaru says something like "Mmhh, with a nickname like 'Zelda', this person is probably a kid. On the internet you never know..."

This helps Hikaru to understand that Sai can play on the internet without giving away his true identity. Because "Zelda" is a nickname anybody can choose. It doesn't give away anything on your identity. You could be a boy or a girl, a teenager or an adult, ...

I believe the nickname "Zelda" was chosen (by the scenarist) because, like you said, anybody knows about "the legend of Zelda" reference even if you didn't play the videogame. Having a person saying "His nickname is 'Zelda', he must be a kid" is something every reader will understand.

Furthermore, Waya knows how to handle a computer and we can safely assume he plays videogames. Akira and Hikaru are all about go, but Waya is more a "normal" or "typical" teenager. Even if he is an insei, he has other interests than go.